# jquery xml in IE(8) not working (even after following all the suggestions i could find here)

Tags: jquery, xml, internet-explorer

Age old problem probably but about to pull my hair out.

I have an `xml` file being loaded from the same folder as the html file.

JS Code:

```
function onxmlReceived(data) {

         if(!($.browser.msie)) {//for Non IE Browsers
         var xmlData = data;                                                            
         }else {// For IE                                   
           var xmlData = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
           xmlData.async = false;
           xmlData.loadXML(data);                                  
         } 

         alert ("Got: "+xmlData);
         alert("Got: "+data);

    $(xmlData).find('energyDM').each(function(){
        d1=[];
        for(var i = 0; i < Rec_Count; i++) {
                something();
            }
    });

}

function graphUpdate(){ 
    $.ajax({ 
    url: "EnergyDM.xml",
    type:"GET",
    dataType: ($.browser.msie) ? "text" : "XML",
    success: onxmlReceived,
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown)
        { 
            alert(textStatus + ' ' + errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

I have two alerts. In IE,

`alert ("Got: "+xmlData);` gives `Got:` in the alert window, where as
 `alert("Got: "+data);` Gives `Got: + the proper xml content` in an alert window

And since the xml is not loaded, I cant access the nodes in the `something()` section

XML file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?> 
- <response>
- <energyDM>
  <edNum>1000</edNum> 
  <TMF>UTC</TMF> 
  <pm339>0.166</pm339><pm340>1327449209</pm340> 
  <ed0000>0.148</ed0000> 
  <et0000>1327449510</et0000> 
  .
  .
```

`alert("Got: "+data);`  correctly shows this XML content.

Am I missing something? I would appreciate any clues. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out something as to why it is not working. Inside the something() function, I had for(var i = 0; i < Rec_Count; i++) { if(i < 10) { d1.push([(parseInt($(this).find('et' + ('0000' + i).substr(-4))*1000, parseFloat($(this).find('ed'+('0000' + i).substr(-4)).text())]); } } I changed this to for(var i = 0; i < Rec_Count; i++) { if(i < 10) { d1.push([(parseInt($(this).find('et000'+i).text(),10))*1000, parseFloat($(this).find('ed000'+i).text())]); } } it works in IE.